# Working with (not uploading) large files in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, large-files, external-process

I manage to upload to my asp.net web app site large files (over 10mb). I have changed the web.config for that reason. However the web app gets idle when I work with those large files on my web-server.

The problem occurs when I create an external process that runs a program that process those large files. It works with smaller files (about 1mb) but the asp.net web app gets idle with no response when the files are large.

Should I make some changes to my web.config file such as memory limit etc?

Answer (score 0):

To increase request time out add this to web.config (you may need different values than "999").

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="999" />
</system.web>
```

and for a specific page add this

```
<location path="somefile.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="999"/>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Or open IIS > Sites > mouse right click > Manage Web Site > Advanced Settings > expand section Connection Limits > increase the value in "Connection Time-Out".

Also see https://www.techcartnow.com/increase-timeout-asp-net-application/.

Comment: Hello, that does not seem to work. I already have set a executionTimeout. I manage to upload a large file but the problem occurs when i do run an external process that works with those files. Then the web app does work for small files but not large ones.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is happening with the external process and the code around it. Can you post your code so we can tell exactly what is happening?